# PostgreSQL: How to insert huge data into table?

Tags: postgresql

Here I need to insert huge records to my database tables. How can I do that in PostgreSQL 9.3 version?

**Example**:

```
 /* Table creation */

 create table tabletest(slno int,name text,lname text, address text, city text);

 /* Records insertion */

 insert into tabletest values -- Here i need to insert thousands of records in a bulk.
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? Is each individual record large, or is it just many records? What exactly is the problem in your current approach of inserting the data?

Comment: How about [that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: I have a excel data sheets to be insert.

Comment: @deceze, and also have sql server tables records to insert into postgreSQL table. There are many records to insert.

Comment: 1) Excel sheets cannot be huge for PostgreSQL :) 2) Export data to CSV (or txt) 3) Use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) `\copy` command. Something like: `\copy tabletest from mydata.csv with delimiter ';'` (read docs for details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use the `COPY` command.

Details available in the [Postgres 9.3 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-copy.html)

Note that the file should be available to the Postgres server machine because `COPY` is meant to be used mainly by DBAs.

And, if you have Excel, you'd have to export the data to CSV format first as Postgres cannot read Excel-formatted data directly.